# Can't run a script with fzf from vim

Tags: vim, fzf, vim-fzf

I have a bash script that assembles some data, then pipes it through fzf for the user to choose, then manipulates the choice, then prints it to stdout.

This simulates the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello | fzf | sed 's/h/j/g'
```

This works great from the command line, but when running it from vim to include in the current buffer, the fzf TUI never displays, and I get ANSI escape sequences included in the result:

[image]

It doesn't matter how I run the command from vim. I've tried `:read !{cmd}`, `:.!{cmd}`, and even `:let a=system('{cmd}')`.

For example, I would expect this to work:

```
:read !echo hello | fzf | sed 's/h/j/g'
```

fzf seems to be confusing stdout for a tty.

I know this isn't a limitation of vim, since if I substitute fzf for another interactive chooser with a tty, it works.

Is there an fzf or vim option to make this work?

Comment: You might want to try the fzf vim plugin

Comment: @d-ben-knoble, this is a script that I run outside of vim too, so I'd like to avoid having a vim version and a command-line version.  AFAICT there's no reason why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim doesn't deal with interactive commands that easily. As you've seen, fzf outputs a lot of code to manipulate the display, and `read` is expecting a raw result.

You can do this with `execute` instead of using `read` directly.
Building off another answer ( [Capture the output of an interactive script in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299155/capture-the-output-of-an-interactive-script-in-vim) ) but changing things up to work with fzf, I've modified @joshtch's solution to work with an arbitrary script, and checked that it works with fzf:

my-fzf-script.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
ls | fzf
```

and the vim side of things:

```
function! <SID>InteractiveFZFCommand()
    let tempfile=tempname()
    execute '!./my-fzf-script.sh >' . shellescape(tempfile)
    try
        silent execute 'read' tempfile
    finally
        call delete(tempfile)
    endtry
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 InteractiveFZFCommand call <SID>InteractiveFZFCommand()
```